# Moving a sharepoint folder from one site to another site using C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, asp.net

I am new to SharePoint.

I have given the flow below.

•   I have a button in visual web part called Archive.

•   On Click of the button I like to move the folder inside the site(A) to another site(B).

•   I used this code to move a folder from a site to another site.

I am getting an `error`:

> "Folder 'Archive' not exist".

What is the reason for this issue?

```
protected void btnArchive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {

                SPWeb spWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;


                string strURl = @"http://server/site/Shared%20Documents/Copies";

                SPFolder spFolder = spWeb.GetFolder(strURl);


                string sDestURL = @"http://server/site/archive/Shared%20Documents/";
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(sDestURL))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            string sSiteName = spWeb.Name;

                            SPFolder subSiteFolder = web.GetFolder(sDestURL + sSiteName);

                            if (!subSiteFolder.Exists)
                            {

                                subSiteFolder = web.Folders.Add(sSiteName);
                                web.Update();

                            }


                            spFolder.CopyTo(sDestURL);

                        }

                    }

            });
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            lblMesg.Text = "Error:" + Ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So? What is your question?

Comment: Hi Akhoy, Apologise for not detailing the issue. I posted the issue which i am getting. Please let me know if you want any input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like the error message says: There is no Folder 'Archive' in the Shared Documents Lib. Are you sure, you need web.GetFolder(sDestURL + sSiteName)? I think "+ sSiteName" is to much

Answer (score 0):

Side note: You need to initialize also the source web inside Elevated Privileges, otherwise it'll use current user privileges.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strURl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
```

However, this should cover it pretty much.

```
private static void RecursiveCopy(SPList objSourceList, SPFolder objSourceFolder, SPFolder objDestinationFolder)
    {
        SPListItemCollection objItems = ((SPDocumentLibrary)objSourceList).GetItemsInFolder(objSourceList.DefaultView, objSourceFolder);

        foreach (SPListItem objItem in objItems)
        {
            //If it's a file copy it.
            if (objItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
            {

                byte[] fileBytes = objItem.File.OpenBinary();
                string DestinationURL = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", objDestinationFolder.Url, objItem.File.Name);

                //Copy the file.
                SPFile objDestinationFile = objDestinationFolder.Files.Add(DestinationURL, fileBytes, true);
                objDestinationFile.Update();
            }
            else
            {
                string dirURL = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", objDestinationFolder.Url, objItem.Folder.Name);
                SPFolder objNewFolder = objDestinationFolder.SubFolders.Add(dirURL);
                objNewFolder.Update();

                //Copy all the files in the sub folder
                RecursiveCopy(objSourceList, objItem.Folder, objNewFolder);
            }
        }
    }

public static void CopyListItems(string SourceSiteURL, string DestinationSiteURL, string ListName)
    {
        string DestinationURL = string.Empty;

        using (SPSite SourceSite = new SPSite(SourceSiteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb SourceWeb = SourceSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                using (SPSite DestinationSite = new SPSite(DestinationSiteURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb DestinationWeb = DestinationSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        DestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        //Get the QA Forms Document libarary from the source web
                        SPList objSourceList = SourceWeb.Lists[ListName];

                        SPList objDestinationList = null;

                        try
                        {
                            objDestinationList = DestinationWeb.Lists[ListName];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //Create a list in the destination web
                            DestinationWeb.Lists.Add(ListName, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                        }

                        objDestinationList = DestinationWeb.Lists[ListName];

                        //Recursively copy all the files and folders
                        RecursiveCopy(objSourceList, objSourceList.RootFolder, objDestinationList.RootFolder);



                        DestinationWeb.Update();
                        DestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511694/copy-folders-when-copying-list-items-from-source-to-destination)